# How to achive that analytics task using cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

i'm trying to create a column family to store some analytics.

This is my cf:

```
CREATE TABLE myKeySpace.trend(
    id uuid, 
    value text, 
    year int,
    month int,
    day int,                        
    counter counter,
primary key(id,year,month,day,value))
```

This is query i need:

1 - Select all values for a specific range of date
    ->This is not a problem because i can do query specifying id, year month and day.

2 - Select all dates ( or range of dates ) for a specific value.

```
->I can't do this because i can't use range for year/month/day with a specific value.

->A solution could be using secondary index but i can't add index on that table because secondary index are not allowed on counter tables.
```

What is a solution to achive what i need?

I hope that my answer is clear.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just use a timestamp column instead? You'll be able to do both queries without an issue?

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to use that table for the second query. You can:

- Create a separate table with values / value ranges as pks and have something else manage that data. You're using a counter table, so I imagine exact accuracy isn't important.
- Use something like Spark with the cassandra connector and use that for the second query.

Answer (score 1):

One table per query is the golden rule in Cassandra. However it looks like you can handle this if you timestamps or timeuuids for storing your time information. When querying you can get the exact dates from the data and bucket it the way you want to show the user.